# Fragment calls onCreateView() after resuming from hold

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I added a ListView to my fragment and now for some reason it is calling the onCreateView() method after resuming from hold. Although the fragment is not destroyed after the hold button of the device is pressed it still creates the fragment again after I resume the device from hold.

This just happens to the fragment where I added the Listview and not to others.

The layout of the fragment looks like that:

```
      <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >

      <ListView
        android:id="@+id/entry_list_view_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
      </ListView>
      </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Is this some kind of bug or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit** when I try to call setRetainnstance(true) I get the Exception

```
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't retain fragements that are nested in other fragments
```

apparently the fregmet is a nested fragment although its actually the only one.

Comment: The fragment may not being getting destroyed, but the View is getting destroyed. I'm willing to bet "onDestroyView()" is getting called. Whether this is a system bug or not, you need to design Fragments to handle the possibility the View will get destroyed because it can happen at any time for a variety of reasons.

Comment: okay so thats just normal? because it happens every time I resume from hold. It didn't happen with a scrollview.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "hold", but I'm assuming either setting the device to sleep or pressing the Home button. Either way, yes.  "OnCreateView" simply means the View is being reinflated because it either was destroyed or never existed in the first place.  Another issue may be that you're actually re-creating the Fragment by accident so it's actually a brand new Fragment instead of re-using the old.

Comment: yeah I meant pressing the button of the device to lock the screen. And why does it destroy the views just of the fragment with the ListView? Is that somehow implemented in the ListView?

Comment: You mentioned in the question it's a nested fragment, so it's probably an issue with how child fragments are handled (which are fragments within fragments or nested fragments). I normally don't use those, so I'm not sure.